# Kubuntu 19.04 doesn't open "4K Video Downloader" normally

Tags: kubuntu, kde, qt, plasma-5

I have installed the program 4K Video Downloader on Kubuntu 19.04 and the .deb package seems to be OK, as shown on the picture below.

[image: Image 1]

But when I search for the program on Kubuntu menu and click to open it, it simply doesn't open. Via terminal, the program opens normally, but the following Qt-related messages appear:

[image: Image 2]

Currently, I use the same program on Ubuntu 19.04 with Gnome and it opens normally. But I wish to migrate to KDE because is so much better. Does anyone know how to fix this kind of problem with Qt? And also: are those errors common on KDE?

Comment: They look like info/warning messages.  If the program works, you can just ignore them.

Comment: perhaps the install method matters. did you just double-click on the .deb or did you use `dpkg -i ` on it in a terminal?

Comment: I double-clicked on the .deb.

Comment: But through dpkg -i on terminal didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here. Seems some issue with the launcher.

Copy the `.desktop` to your Desktop. It will launch from there no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the menu icon /edit application/application
put /bin/bash -c  before 4kvideodownloader in the command box